# jQuery UI infinite loop when clicking on auto selectable input which is above a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a case where I have an input that sits on top of everything on a page.

The input has a script that auto selects all the text in it when it is focused.

However when I open a jQuery UI dialog the browser is put into an infinite focus/blur loop.

Anyway to prevent this happening? Or am I doing anything wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="dialog">I am a dialog</div>
<input id="input" value="Click on me then look in your console" />
```

JS:

```
$('.dialog').dialog({
    modal: true
});

var blur = 0;
var focus = 0;

$('#input').on('focus', function() {
    focus++;
    console.log('focus #'+focus);
    var inp = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        inp.select();
    }, 1);
});

$('#input').on('blur', function() {
    blur++;
    console.log('blur #'+blur);
});
```

CSS:

```
#input {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XB8L/2/

Comment: Strangely enough, the loop only seems to happen when the dialog is open. If the dialog is closed, the counters work just fine.

Comment: It also only happens if the dialog is modal.

Comment: Looks like a bug in jquery UI 1.10.x: http://jsfiddle.net/3XB8L/3/  using UI 1.9.2

Comment: I'd expect the issue to be arising from here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L261 and here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L288

Comment: @KevinB ya seems fair